# Daterangepicker event on icon click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

My calendar shows up after icon click with this code.

```
const initCalendar = () => {
  $('#date').datepicker({autoclose: true, format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', todayHighlight: true});
};
```

I don't have any onclick events in my JS code, but my icon have an event in google chrome console. `span.input-group-addon`

But daterangepicker doesn't

```
const initDateRangePicker = () => {
  $('#date2').daterangepicker({
    locale: {
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
      cancelLabel: 'Clear'
    },
    showDropdowns: true,
    autoUpdateInput: false,
  });
};
```

HTML code is similar in both examples.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label class="control-label small">Date range</label>

  <div class="input-group date" id="date">
    <span class="input-group-addon btn">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wan't to open daterangepicker on icon click. How can I do this?

Comment: is it a plugin being used for datepicker or is it a jqueryui?

Comment: can you create a jsFiddle plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#options) for daterangepicker exposes a event that you can trigger called `show.daterangepicker`. You can use it like so:

```
$(document).on('click' , '#id_of_your_date_range_picker_icon' , function(){
    $('#date2').trigger('show.daterangepicker');
});
```

**P.S.** replace `'#id_of_your_date_range_picker_icon'` with the ID or class of your icon.

Answer (score 6):

@Alexander Solonik, your solution didn't help. Anyway, thank you for helping.
Here is how I solved my problem^

```
$('.input-group-addon').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#dat2').click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

$('#date2').data('daterangepicker').show()